# Configuring multiple instances of Jboss 5.1 AS in a single machine

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, jboss-tools

Developers sometimes have to work on different versions of their product and usually tend to configure / run multiple instances of JBoss application server on the same machine. In order to bring the second or third instance developers tend to tweak various configuration files to avoid port collisions. Are there any tools which provide a better way to monitor and manage creation of new instances and handle such issues.

Comment: primarily on the Windows platform

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know, if you're running a network with few restrictions (don't know if this is feasible using DHCP or if you need to manually setup TcpIp addresses for developer machines) to speed up the process you can assign to a single machine more than one IP address and then start JBoss binding each JBoss instance to a single IP address using the -b parameter.

Regards

Massimo

Comment: Assigning more than one IP address for a machine will not be possible in our environment.